# Выборка лет из бд MS SQL

Tags: база-данных, sql-server, datetime, group-by

Есть таблица, в которой есть поля Date (datetime) и Money (float).

Записей около 15 миллионов.

Т.е. за несколько лет, хранится информация по продажам товаров на каждый день.

**Необходимо представить отчёт по сумме продаж по годам.**

То, что у меня получилось:

```
SELECT      t.[Year],
            SUM(t.Money)
FROM        (
                SELECT  DATEPART(YEAR, mss.Date) AS [Year],
                        mss.Money
                FROM    Sales AS mss
            ) t
GROUP BY    t.[Year]
ORDER BY    t.[Year]
```

**НО, данный запрос отрабатывает примерно за 3-4 секунды, есть возможность ускорить это время?**

Comment: Сильно сомневаюсь что это возможно. Даже просто поднять с диска 15 млн записей не мгновенная операция. Если нужно выполнять это очень часто, можно задуматься о кешировании в другой таблице уже готовой суммарной информации по предыдущим годам, что бы не пересчитывать постоянно по первичным данным

Comment: Сделать предрасчётную таблицу, с суммами продаж (и иными показателями, если надо), посчитанными за сутки, и считать уже из неё, а не из исходной таблицы.

Comment: Подумать о другой БД )